# Connection to server via pdo is not working, how to add port to the connection?

Tags: php, mysql, pdo

I'm hosting a domain at 1&1 and I want to connect with my database using pdo. Without using a port, it doesn't work and I don't know how to add the port to my code....

```
$mysql_host = "xxxxxxxxx";
$mysql_username = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
$mysql_database = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";
$mysql_password = "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx";

$pdo = new PDO("mysql:host=" . $mysql_host . ";dbname=" . $mysql_database , $mysql_username , $mysql_password);
```

Im not sure but maybe the Problem doesn't go together with the connection, but with the mysql-commands...

```
  $schematic_statement = $pdo->prepare('SELECT title FROM schematics-download WHERE id = 1');
  $schematic_statement->bindParam('title', $Title);
  $schematic_statement->execute();
  $TITLE = $schematic_statement->fetch();

  echo ($TITLE);
```

Thank you for your help!

Comment: See [the docs](http://us3.php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.connection.php).

Comment: Read the manual maybe? http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.connections.php Notice [this user contributed note](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.connections.php#114822).

Comment: you also appear to try and bind a column here, you can't do that.

Comment: and this `FROM schematics-download` - mysql thinks you want to do math here. So, your code failed in too many ways. I can't see what you posted even work with the port or not.

Comment: I would also recommend setting `PDO::ERRORMODE_EXCEPTION` - you'll then be able to see where the error is - see [docs](http://be2.php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php)

Comment: After the port issue you will find multiple issues with your `title` here. e.g. `title` in the query is not a placeholder so the binding won't map. Also unclear why you'd want to bind that, if you already have the value why `select` something? Later you fetch which returns an array so `$TITLE` can't be echoed.

Comment: @chris85 Right you are ^

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> *"Without using a port, it doesn't work and I don't know how to add the port to my code...."*

This (probably) has nothing to do with porting.

Your code however, contains a few (syntax) errors.

1) You can't bind a column (or a table)

Your `SELECT title` and `bindParam('title'` suggest it.

2) `FROM schematics-download` - mysql is interpreting that as `FROM schematics` **MINUS** `download`, therefore you need to escape the table name.

I.e.:

```
FROM `schematics-download`
```

If this is a porting issue, then [this user contributed note](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.connections.php#118381) shows you how to do it.

```
$conn = new PDO('mysql: host=123.4.5.6;dbname=test_db;port=3306','username','password');
                                                      ^^^^^^^^^^
```

and from http://php.net/manual/en/ref.pdo-mysql.connection.php

```
More complete examples:

mysql:host=localhost;port=3307;dbname=testdb
mysql:unix_socket=/tmp/mysql.sock;dbname=testdb
```

As for error handling, PDO has that:

- http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.error-handling.php

which would have thrown you a few.

Taken from Chris' comment:

> *"Later you fetch which returns an array so $TITLE can't be echoed."*

Take a look at the documentation on fetching data in PDO:

- http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.fetch.php

There are ample examples in there to show you on to do this.

Comment: Random question regarding your comment made on the OP:  could you ever use a variable for a column name?  I've read that using variables within a query is generally not a good idea unless you sanitize inputs but I'm just curious.  Not sure if there is even a use case for a query with a variable column name.

Comment: @cchoe1 Yes you can use a variable for a column/table name, given it doesn't contain any characters that mysql will complain about. They're best to be ticked `\`` in any case, yet a safelist does work well also. There can be cases where a column/table needs to be used from a form let's say and as a pre-defined set of choices, so it can be done.